# Why git give different output when run from within Python?

Tags: git, bash, python-2.7, shell

I have a local git repository for which the branch `this_branch` is checked out, and the branch `master` is also available. I run the following command from `bash` in the terminal

```
$ { git rebase master this_branch ; } 2>&1
```

and I see this output

> Current branch this_branch is up to date.

I also have a python script, in which I cd to the same directory, and then run the same command. I'm running Python 2.7 and using `commands.getstatusoutput`, so the command ends up being run as

```
>>> import os
>>> cmd = 'git rebase master this_branch'
>>> pipe = os.popen('{ ' + cmd + '; } 2>&1', 'r')
>>> text = pipe.read()
>>> print text
```

and I see this output

> First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...

At the bash terminal I find no git-related symbols (`$ env | grep -i git` shows nothing).

This leaves me with 2 questions:

1. What else could be affecting the 2 different shells (terminal and Python's `os.popen`) that tells `git` to change its output?
2. What should I use instead of `commands.getstatusoutput` to more closely mimic behaviour at the terminal?

Comment: The `{` and `}` don't actually do anything useful whatsoever here. They're grouping syntax in shell, but a single-command group is pointless.

Comment: Also, `os.popen()` is deprecated -- use the `subprocess` module instead when writing new code. See docs @ https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-os-popen-os-popen2-os-popen3 re: replacing `os.popen()`.

Comment: that said -- (1) the *usual* thing that makes `popen` output different from interactive shell output is stdout, in the latter, being a TTY, whereas it's necessarily a pipe in the former. (2) this *particular* output makes me disbelieve your implicit claim that both commands are run in the same directory with git trees in the same initial state.

Comment: As per @CharlesDuffy's point 2, I'm fairly sure Git doesn't care in these circumstances whether it's run from a TTY or not, and even if it did it wouldn't change in this way. Are you sure you didn't do a `git fetch` or a `git commit` or something in between the two tests?

Comment: A [mcve] which did the work of creating a git tree (either new, or cloned from a public source) in the state you're using to test would let others see your error for themselves, which would make the claims referenced in (2) easier to believe.

Comment: To be a bit more concrete/explicit: If all the commits on `this_branch` were included in `master`, then the message in question is outright expected, no matter where you're running `git` from.

Comment: This is from legacy code, hence the old-fashioned `getstatusoutout`.
I am sure there were no other `git` command between the 2 tests: I paused in a python debugger, switched to a shell, ran the command, came back to debugger, and then ran the comand there.
All the commits of `master` are included in `this_branch`. This is a script which is repeatedly run, so last thing that happened in this dir was the same `rebase` command. And I was trying to see how to distinguish "rebase actually made a change" from "just a re-run, nothing changed" when I noticed the discrepancy.

Comment: "the message in question is outright expected". I am not surprised at either message, only that the message differs depending on which shell is used

Comment: Piping the output from `git` through `cat` has no effect on the respective messages